# Name on the visa

Tags: schengen

On my Schengen visa, my name is written as it is on my passport: first name then last name. However, on the visa it says: surname, first name.

Will passport control accept it?

I have travelled with it already to Amsterdam (multiple-entry visa), but I am worried that Munich would have an issue with this. What do you all think?

Comment: All names are the same on the different pieces but in a different order? If so, they will be accepted. We already have a few questions which have several answers.

Comment: dda no no...both passport and visa my name is written the same way first name then last name...but the way the visa itself (like the heading of the section) it says: surname, first name..  so basically according to the visa my name should have been written last name first name...but the dutch embassy wrote it first name last name.....i hope im making sense

Comment: @HaniAlZaid In English, "Surname" and "Last name" mean the same thing. It's hard to tell whether you're following the same convention here.

Comment: @Sneftel it seems to me that the order of the names is First, Last (for example "Hani AlZaid"), but because the visa *label* for the name field is "Surname, Name" (which you can confirm by searching for images of Schengen visas) the visa incorrectly indicates that the surname is "Hani" and the given name "AlZaid."

Answer (score 4):

I have had the same problem with the British Visa in 2016.
Before to even travel to wards that country I decided to show the mistake to the British embassy in Algiers. They kept the passport with them and 2 days later they gave it back to me with a new visa after they barred upon the previous one. The lady in charge said to me :"You did well in showing us the mistake otherwise in case they see the mistake at the airport control they will not let get in!". I paid no extra fee nor did I have have to submit any other document as the fault was theirs. This is all what I can help you with. Good luck!